# I want to reload my sidebar component (vue js + laravel)

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Is there any way to reload the sidebar component from other vue component ?
I got a menuLabel at the sidebar which will show the number of order in pending status. So I want to update the sidebar menuLabel whenever I change the status from pending to others.

For example, When I click submit or some button in SalesOrder.vue, I want to reload the sidebar.

Sample component code:

```
export const Routes = [
{
        path: '/admin',
        components: { default: ThemeContent, header: ThemeHeader, sidebar: ThemeSidebar, footer: ThemeFooter },
        children: [
            { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardAdmin },   
            { path: 'salesorder', component: SalesOrder},   
],
meta: { requiresAdmin: true }
},
```

Comment: The sample component code is in the route.js

Comment: By reload the sidebar, do you mean you want to make an ajax request to get the latest orders data?

Comment: Hi Digital Drifter, for example, there is one pending order and this will show one in the sidebar menuLabel. When I change the order from pending to delivered and submit, i want to the sidebar menuLabel to update from one to zero because the menuLabel is showing the number of pending order.

Comment: My sample code is in here https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-reload-sidebar-component/40540

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for helping me, I have found a way for me to interact from one component to another which is using a bus event vuejs.
https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/

Answer (score 0):

You can separate 1st sidebar to external component and 2nd to another. Then include both components to your sidebar block and hide/show them whenever you want.

```
<sidebar>
  <first-sidebar :trigger="boolean"></first-sidebar>
  <second-sidebar :trigger="boolean"></second-sidebar>
</sidebar>
```

Then in your first sidebar component

```
<template>
  <div v-if="trigger">
    <!-- ... -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['trigger']
}
</script>
```

And finally second sidebar component

```
<template>
  <div v-if="!trigger">
    <!-- ... -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['trigger']
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks I understand but do you have any sample I can refer to ?

Comment: My sample code is in here 
https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-reload-sidebar-component/40540

Comment: you already have sidebar component. Now you need component with second sidebar. I can't figure out where your second sidebar is. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44700257/hide-a-component-in-vue-js check this to see how to hide/show components

Comment: Hmm...ok. So after I create a second sidebar then what should I do?